# Various Conditional Statements in VBA

Tags: excel

What is the most efficient way to build the IN conditional statement in Excel? Here is an example:

Suppose a user select Office in cell A1, IN in cell B1 and SF,LA,NY in cell C1.

How do I dynamically translate that statement in cell D1 to Office IN ('SF','LA','NY')?

If the user instead writes SF,OC,PD,LA, the statement will then become Office IN ('SF','OC','PD','LA').

Thanks in advance.

Rob

I've tried to come up with various excel functions but fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use concatenation. Try-

```
=A1& " " & B1 & " ('"&SUBSTITUTE(C1,",","','")&"')"
```

Or using `TEXTJOIN()`.

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",1,A1:B1,"('"&SUBSTITUTE(C1,",","','")&"')")
```

[image]

Comment: @Phantasmic1980 Glad to know! If it helps then please accept the answer (tick mark it).